# E003 type error with Bootstrap Glyphicons and JavaFX WebView

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, javafx-2, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I'm have a really weird bug, heres the setup:

I have a web app running in openshift, all is good and runs great in Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, Safari and Android WebView.

But because I need some hardware level access for a few functions, I created a JavaFX application running a WebView with a JavaScript interface for the hardware functions.

Everything works and runs (although with low FPS) except for the Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons.

**Here is a screenshot from Chrome:**

[image: Here is a screenshot from Chrome]

**Here is a screenshot from JavaFX WebView**

[image: Here is a screenshot from JavaFX WebView]

**The RIA, client side is running:**
-Bootstrap 3 and Glyphicons (from the CDN)
-Bootstrap Modal (from the server)
-JQuery 2.0.3 (from CDN)
-AngularJS (from CDN)

**UPDATE:**
After some testing, it appears that Glyphicons from Bootstrap 2.3.2 do work as expected inside JavaFX. But I'm not willing to go back to BS 2.3.2

Comment: Try your app with [Java 8](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html), and if that doesn't work, create an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) and file it in a bug report against the [JavaFX Issue Tracker](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

Comment: Thanks, I'm downloading the JDK8 right now, will report as soon as I test.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!, It was fixed with JavaFX 8!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap glyph icons show in [Java 8](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html).

This is (likely) because JavaFX in [Java 8 adds @font-face support](http://fxexperience.com/2012/12/use-webgoogle-fonts-in-javafx/) which was not present in Java 7 (JavaFX 2.2).

Related JavaFX issue tracker issues which added support in Java 8:

- [RT-10343 CSS add support for CSS3 @font-face](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-10343) (uses JavaFX css styles).
- [RT-17428 WebView-component to render CSS @font-face declarations](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-17428) (uses HTML css styles).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I switched to [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/), which I found does work with JavaFX 2 WebView.